# using backend files nodejs

Tags: node.js, web-applications

Sorry, It might be very novice problem but I am new to node and web apps and just have been stuck on this for couples of days.

I have been working with a API called "Face++" that requires user to upload images to detect faces. So basically users needed to upload images to my webapps backend and my backend would do an API request with that image. I somehow managed to upload the files at my node's backend using tutorial provided below but now I am struggling how to use those image files. I really don't know how to have access to those files. I thought writing just the filepath/filename would help but it did not. I am really new at webapps.

I used tutorial from here: https://coligo.io/building-ajax-file-uploader-with-node/
to upload my files at back-end.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use the Face++ REST API node client
https://www.npmjs.com/package/faceppsdk

As per in documentation it requires a live URL on web. Then you have to upload your files into remote location (You may upload files to a [Amazon S3 Bucket](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-node))

And also you check the [sample codes from Documentation](https://console.faceplusplus.com/documents/7078069) where you can upload directly to Face++